# How do I configure mongodb to remove old log files?

Tags: mongodb, logging, windows-10

I've read the mongodb docs and am rotating my log files on Windows 10. However, the number of logs grow until I manually delete them. I'd like to keep 30 days worth of logs.

I was hoping there was a config setting similar to NLog where I can specify how many files to keep before they are re-written. Maybe I am misunderstanding something in the docs. What is the "best practice" for automatically removing old log files?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the easiest way to do this without 3rd party utilities is to create a batch file that runs each night via Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

years later, but still helpful might be this cmd-script. It's written to remove old stuff in my profile, but really simple to extend:

```
@echo off
@setlocal

REM Remove everything older then "/D" days (ten/10 days in our examples below)
REM BUT we can not remove directories with files in it, so we do it in two-steps ways:
REM 1st remove all files by using the command: del
REM 2nd remove all files by using the command: rd

REM cleanup %TMP%
forfiles -p "%TMP%"                   -m * /D -10 /C "cmd /c del /s/q @path > nul 2> nul"
forfiles -p "%TMP%"                   -m * /D -10 /C "cmd /c  rd /s/q @path > nul 2> nul"

REM cleanup %TEMP%
forfiles -p "%TEMP%"                  -m * /D -10 /C "cmd /c del /s/q @path > nul 2> nul"
forfiles -p "%TEMP%"                  -m * /D -10 /C "cmd /c  rd /s/q @path > nul 2> nul"

REM cleanup the Downloads folder in the current profile
forfiles -p "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads" -m * /D -10 /C "cmd /c del /s/q @path > nul 2> nul"
forfiles -p "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads" -m * /D -10 /C "cmd /c  rd /s/q @path > nul 2> nul"

@endlocal
@echo on
```

Comment: Thanks, I may try and extend this to suit my purpose.